# ADO DataSet or Entity Framework SELECT Constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, ado.net

I am using C# and VS2012, with a SQL Server 2008 database, exclusively driven by stored procedure.

I have a fair amount of experience with using the ADO DataSet model's DataTableAdapter to autogenerate useful methods for CRUD operations.  The ease with which I can wire up a table or stored procedure (and then later refresh the schema if I need to) is very useful in my RAD environment - we add fields and revise stored procedures often.  I know how to perform CRUD operations as method calls, but I do not see how to fashion a constructor that will execute a SELECT procedure. I am looking for a workaround for what I see as a limitation of this model, and recently started experimenting with the Entity Framework to see if I can overcome it, but don't have enough experience with it yet to tell if this is possible.

To clarify, using the DataSet model, I can get a strongly-typed Person row from my database like this when I use it:

```
PersonDataSetTableAdapters.Persons adapter = new PersonDataSetTableAdapters.Persons();
PersonRow person = adapter.GetByID(personID);
```

What I'd prefer to do is use a SELECT constructor pattern that would look like this:

```
Person person = new Person(personID);
```

I've tried to create my own helper classes to provide this, but one way or another I end up having to explicitly set each property in the constructor - and then maintain that code when the schema changes.  This is exactly what I want to avoid doing.

Because I want to have my cake and eat it too - I want strongly typed objects and autogenerated code that is reasonably easy to refresh when the schema changes.  I also want to be able inherit from these base classes and extend them with partial classes when appropriate.  I don't see how to meet all these goals with the DataSet model.  None of the EF samples I've found seem to address my pattern closely enough to follow.

Can I fashion simple SELECT constructors with ADO?  Can you provide a simple code sample that illustrates how?

Comment: Why a "select constructor"? A "select factory method" I could understand..

Comment: In fact, most of my entities don't require inheritance.  While factory methods are a sensible approach for the small percentage that do, I think parameterless or single-parameter constructors will be adequate for the bulk of our codebase, and I favor (what I perceive to be) a lightweight approach.  To put it in context, I'm looking to rework a system that was overengineered (given our tiny maintenance staff) in the first place.  In pursuit of that, I want to replace our cumbersome SQLClient DAL with something UI-friendly and semi-automatic, so we can focus on business logic.

Comment: I wasn't proposing anything heavy - indeed, as the aco-uthor of "dapper" I applaud lightweight - but: a method that *returns* an instance is a lot easier to do than a constructor. Heck, it is a one-liner with dapper.